# NavMesh проходит под мешем 3д модели. как исправить?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Сделал самую начальную настройку NavMesh'a (инициализировал), только запёк и всё, никакие слои не  назначал и не менял. Вопрос - как можно провести тропу через эту дверь? Я так понимаю нужно поработать со слоями?[image: Скрин экрана с Unity]

Comment: а navMash вообще отображается в процессе игры? Если нет, то в чем конкретно проблема? Это как-нибудь мешает?

Comment: Дело в том, что нужно, чтобы игрок мог проходить через эту дверь, но здесь NavMesh прерывается, вопрос - как провести NavMesh через эту дверь?

Comment: у тебя какие-то реальные проблемы возникли что бы проходить сквозь дверь, или ты запаниковал до того как они возникли и создал вопрос?

Comment: Опишу подробнее)) У меня есть, можно сказать, "зомби" - простенький ИИ. Его задача преследовать игрока, когда тот попадает в зону видимости "зомби". Для реализации движения "зомби", я использую NavMesh. Проблема - когда я прохожу своим игроком через дверь, то соответсвенно "зомби" не может пройти через неё, т.к. NavMesh прерывается в дверном проёме. Ожидаю - ответ, как можно провести NavMesh через дверной проём. Это я уже протестировал и пишу с уже существующей проблемой)

Comment: чисто в теории тебе нужно проставить галочку Height Mesh https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-HeightMesh.html?_ga=2.133149709.2090824715.1611265873-389611424.1611265873 и запечь NavMesh с высотами

Comment: не помогает т.к. работаю с NavMesh взятым с гита, встроенная версия устарела и юнити рекомендует использовать с гита

Comment: может быть как то со слоями поиграться нужно?

Comment: В смысле устарела и юнити рекомендует использовать с гита? Если бы она устарела то ее бы убрали из юнити. Если бы она стала необязательной к установке - ее бы убрали и дали возможность установить из ассет стора. Ты явно куда-то не туда побрел. Где ты вообще видел такую рекомендацию?